# How do i get the view item using a ResourceCursorAdapter when i click a widget in the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have this particular problem which follows me since couple days. I used the search but couldn't found any article witch would be helpful for my problem yet. i guess it also a problem of my search.
however, back to my question.

I use a ResourceCursorAdapter to fill my ListView.
My ListView Item looks like..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/download_cb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/some_bt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pdf_ib"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/download_pb"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Adapter:

```
private final class ListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter implements
        DownloadCallback, OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener {

            public ListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ItemHolder holder = (ItemHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.url = cursor.getString(..);

        holder.titleTv.setText(cursor.getString(..));
        holder.descriptionTv.setText(cursor.getString(..));
        ...

        if(cursor.getInt(..) == 1) {
            holder.progress.setVisible(View.GONE);          
        }

        if(cursor.getInt(...) == 1) {
            holder.downloadCb.setEnabled(isConnectedToNet); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
        ItemHolder holder = new ItemHolder();

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        holder.titleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
        holder.descriptionTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description_tv);
        ...

        holder.downloadCb.setEnabled(isConnectedToNet);                 
        holder.downloadCb.setOnClickListener(this);         
        holder.downloadCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                    
                prepare2Download();

                DownItem di = new DownItem();
                di.url = holder.url;        /// <========= to do this               

                // start async downloader and notify progressbar "holder.downPb"                    
                Download serverTaskObject = new Download();                 
                serverTaskObject.execute(currDownholder.copy());    

                holder.downPb.setVisibility(View.GONE);     // <======== and this.          
            }
        });

        holder.pdfIb = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pdf_ib);
        holder.pdfIb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start new activity and load website.
                openUrl(holder.url);    // <============ or this.
            }
        });

        holder.downPb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pb_law_download);
        holder.downPb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        view.setTag(cachedItem);
        return view;
    }

    ...

    private static class LawItemCache {
        TextView titleTv;
        TextView descriptionTv;
        ...

        CheckBox downloadCb;
        ImageButton pdfIb;

        ProgressBar downPb;

        String url;
        IProgressListener listener;
    }
}
```

My question is.. 
When i click on a Button or a Checkbox in the ListView i want to make some changes in the specific View holder, like to make the Progressbar visible or gone. 
I couldn't figure out yet how i get the View holder within my adapter to make my changes.

I hope i explained it well enough to get into the point of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this a lot and finally managed to get it working! I have a checkbox in my Row and an using a ResourceCursorAdapter. The trick was to realize that the checkbox clicked handler needs to be bound either in getView() or newView() while the holder needs to be associated in bindView(). That way the currently displayed rows in the ListView always have the correct holder info. Here are my bindView and getView methods:

```
 public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                Log.i(CN,"bindView");
                TextView todoTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.todoItemText);
                Log.i(CN,"bindView set txt");
                TextView todoTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.todoItemTitle);
                Log.i(CN,"bindView set title");
                CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.todoChecked);
                Log.i(CN,"bindView set check");

                IOweRowTag tag=(IOweRowTag)cBox.getTag();
                int pos=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Todos._ID));
                Log.i(CN,"getView: no tag on "+pos);
                tag=new IOweRowTag();
                tag.id=pos;
                cBox.setTag(tag);

//              IOweRowTag irt=(IOweRowTag)view.getTag();
//              if(irt!=null)
//                  Log.i(CN,"Got irt id="+irt.id);
//              else
//                  Log.i(CN,"No id");
//              
                Log.i(CN,"got title="+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Todos.TITLE)));
                Log.i(CN,"got txt="+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Todos.TEXT)));

                todoTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Todos.TITLE)));
                todoTxt.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Todos.TEXT)));
                cBox.setChecked(true);

            }




        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View tmpView=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            Log.i(CN,"getView:"+position);
            final CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.todoChecked);
            IOweRowTag tag=(IOweRowTag)cBox.getTag();
            cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    IOweRowTag tag=(IOweRowTag)v.getTag();
                    if(tag==null)
                        Log.i(CN,"checkbox clicked no tag");
                    else
                        Log.i(CN,"checkbox clicked tag="+tag.id);
                   if(cBox.isChecked()) { 
                       Log.i(CN," Checked!"); 
                       // do some operations here 
                   }   
                   else{ 
                       Log.i(CN,"NOT Checked!"); 
                       // do some operations here 
                   }
               }
                });


            return tmpView;
        }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. by the time i already changed my code to get it run. but i will keep your answer in mind. the day will come i run into this problem again :) thx!!!